# Command Pattern Example

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to grasp command patterns, and I was wondering if you can give me a real life example of what a command pattern would look like.

On a side note, is a switch statement a command pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#C++

Comment: Alexandrescu in his epic _Modern C++ Design_ (modern as in the year 2001) provides a long and elaborate explanation of why Command pattern is basically a function object but separate named and described in a Holy Book.

Comment: wiki shows code examples, I am looking for a realife example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not! Switch isn't a design pattern, but a control structure which can be use instead of multiple if statements. The Command Design Pattern it's object oriented and if you use some switch statements for implementing this design pattern, you must avoid confusing one with another.

Here it's a link where you can read more about command pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command